# Possible layout with Flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a container that looks like so...

[image: Flexbox]

I'm trying to accomplish this using flexbox only getting nowhere. Is this possible or shall I use nested rows and fixed heights?

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  height: 650px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
  flex: 1;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  background: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  background: green;
  flex: 1;
}

div:nth-child(4) {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>First</div>
  <div>second</div>
  <div>third</div>
  <div>fourth</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to wrap the 2 small and the one beneath those 2

Comment: what should be the natural order of these blocks on mobile? Can you assign a number to the blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap second/third/fourth

*Updated: IE need `flex-grow: 1;`*

```css
.main, .wrap {
  display:flex;
  height:250px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.main > div:nth-child(1){
  background:red;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.main > div:nth-child(2){
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.wrap div:nth-child(1){
  background:blue;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.wrap div:nth-child(2){
  background:green;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.wrap div:nth-child(3){
  background:yellow;
  flex-basis: 100%;             /*  this will make the 3rd to take full
                                    width and wrap into a new line       */
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>First</div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div>second</div>
    <div>third</div>
    <div>fourth</div>
  </div>
</div>
```